# Only select one record if there are more than one of only certain same value of record

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

In the sql, i wanted all the record but for value `RM` in column `MCCU` occurs twice..but i'm in a situation that cannot distinct it because the value of misc of both value are not same..

How can i make if `MCCU` have more than one `RM` and then only select the one that have higher position in column `POSI` and in the `misc` column, add up their two value together. Hope idea to solve it. Thank you very much!

This is my sql statement

```
select * from Oclaimc Where cono='NP' and CLNO='7150000032'
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and also add wanted result? (And tag the dbms used...)

Comment: @jarlh - you can assume by attached image.

Comment: @curiousguy, I have no idea what tool that is...

Comment: im using sql~~thanks for reply everyone

Comment: @jarlh - not an issue. actually I am more using sql server so I get the idea. :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sql server~~ :)

Comment: @jarlh hi..any idea? :)

Comment: @Jan, can't you show us the expected output (with table data as in the image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no column names `misc` in your image.  I am assuming you need to sum `gamntMisc` and `gttlMisc`.

So try this. Add other columns when needed.

```
select max(CONO) as CONO,max(CLNO) as CLNO,max(posi) as posi,MCCU,
sum(gamntMisc) as totalgamntMisc,sum(gttlMisc) as totalgttlMisc from Oclaimc
where cono='NP' and CLNO='7150000032'
group by mccu
```

Note: Query will fail if you remove the where clause. If you need this result for each combination of `cono` and `clno` then change the group by clause to 
`group by cono,clno,mccu`

Comment: hi..thank you very much!!
but i'm not really understand, can you explain me, i appreciate it :)
1) the max function for cono and clno means what? cause when i google max function, it means to returns the largest value of the selected column.



2)why the group by for mccu is necessary? cause when i remove it,the query can't run.
truly appreciated.

Comment: So the query is grouping by `mccu` as you have 3 distinct values for it and that is what you need in output. The most important rule of group by function is that the column in select statement should either be in gropu by clause, or they should use any aggregated function. Now even though the `cono` and `clno` values are same for each group of `mccu`, the SQL will not know if they are. So using Max allows us to bypass the group by rule and get the desired result.

Comment: You can further google `group by` and do some case studies to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
 select *
  from oclaimc
 where cono = 'NP'
   and clno = '7150000032'
   and mccu <> 'RM'

 union

 select *
  from (select *
          from oclaimc
         where cono = 'NP'
           and clno = '7150000032'
           and mccu = 'RM'
         order by posi)
 where rownum = 1
```